# How to set text in Carbon textfield on OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, macos-carbon

I'm trying to set the text of a textfield using the Carbon API like this:

```
ControlID editId = {'EDIT', 3};
ControlRef ctrl;
GetControlByID(GetWindowRef(), &editId, &ctrl);
CFStringRef title = CFSTR("Test");      
OSErr er = SetControlData(ctrl, kControlEntireControl, kControlEditTextTextTag, CFStringGetLength(title), title);
CFRelease(title);
```

I'm using the C++ code template of XCode, so GetWindowRef() is a call to the predefined TWindow class. The OSErr return value gives me noErr, but my textfield only contains garbage.
It doesn't matter if I set the attribute of my textfield to Unicode or not.

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does the `GetControlID`(...) return? Is it `noErr`?

As a `ControlRef` is also a `HIViewRef`, you can also use the function:

`HIViewSetText` to set the text. This is documented to work with functions that accept `kControlEditTextCFStringTag`.

By the way, the line you wrote:

```
CFRelease(title);
```

Will cause problems. One should only release objects that have been made using functions that have Create or Copy in the API name. You'll want to read: "Introduction to Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation" -- search in the Xcode documentation.

Comment: Does the HIViewSetText work? It seems a lot simpler to call than the calls currently being used.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this did the trick:

```
SetControlData(ctrl, kControlEditTextPart, kControlStaticTextCFStringTag, sizeof(title), &title);
```

Since this seems to be very old API, a better way seems to be:

```
HIViewSetText(ctrl, title);
```

Thx to Lyndsey for the hints.